# sql split after certain lenght of charcters to new row

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a record in one of the column and it looks like below:

```
132007700013213860001321264000
```

I want to split without using any delimiter based on char length of 10. After every 10 characters i need the records in a new line. Like below

```
1320077000
1321386000
1321264000
```

Comment: Based on SSMS, I removed the MySQL tag.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  Also, SQL doesn't operate in "lines".  Tables have rows and columns.

Comment: What's the maximum length of this string? *Could* it have 100's of undelimited values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select left(col, 10) as x10, convert(varchar(max), stuff(col, 1, 10, '')) as rest
      from t
      union all
      select left(rest, 10), stuff(rest, 1, 10, '')
      from cte
      where rest <> ''
     )
select x10
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=416ec7dd4fe99a591929941ec7255b3f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "rest" of recursive query "cte".

Comment: @user8521874 . . . The db<>fiddle. shows that this works.  I added an explicit type-cast in the answer to handle this issue, if you have it.

Comment: You seem to love recursive CTE (I've seen them in many posts from you) seemingly not realizing how slow they are and that those problems can be solved with a *non-recursive* tally table/function.

Answer (score 2):

If the string is fixed width you could use 3 SUBSTRING functions and CROSS APPLY to 'unpivot' the 3 columns into 1 column, called 'new_col'.

```
declare @txtTable   table(txt       char(30) not null)

insert @txtTable(txt) values 
('132007700013213860001321264000'),
('999999999999999999999999999999');

select u.*
from @txtTable t
    cross apply (values (substring(t.txt, 1, 10),
                         substring(t.txt, 11, 10),
                         substring(t.txt, 21, 10))) v(c1, c2, c3)
     cross apply (values (v.c1),(v.c2),(v.c3)) u(new_col);
```

```
new_col
1320077000
1321386000
1321264000
9999999999
9999999999
9999999999
```

Comment: i cant declare as i have more than 1 records to declare txt so i need to pass my column there which has multiple rows

Answer (score 1):

All credit goes to Gordon Linoff. I just added casting to make it work.

Somehow the DB Fiddle sample worked, but in SSMS it was an error.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (col VARCHAR(30));
INSERT @tbl (col) VALUES
('132007700013213860001321264000'),
('999999999999999999999999999999');

WITH cte as 
(
    SELECT CAST(LEFT(col, 10) AS VARCHAR(10)) as x10, CAST(stuff(col, 1, 10, '') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) as rest
    FROM @tbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(LEFT(rest, 10) AS VARCHAR(10)), STUFF(rest, 1, 10, '')
    FROM cte
    WHERE rest <> ''
)
SELECT x10
FROM cte;
```